# Generating custom projection in pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

I have little experience with pyproj, but I want to achieve the following task:

I have a trajectory of a robot, given in lat/long coordinates which I want to convert to x/y Coordinates. In aerospace sciences, we used the NED coordinate system for this, therefore I want to transfer a bunch of lat/long coordinates to local x/y coordinates whereby the first x/y coordinate shall be at 0/0,(which is typically just the start of the trajectory).

So I have been trying to use the PyProj library, which sucessfully converts lat/long to x/y, however the coordinate system in which the result is given is that of england, however ideally I want the 0/0-point to be my first lat/long point. So I though perhaps it would be possible to define a custom coordinate system originating at a specific coordinate system, but couldn't find anything on google.

Therefore: does anyone know how I can define a NED coordinate System at a specific lat/long combination?

Here is my code so far:

```py
import pyproj as proj

crs_wgs = proj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')  # assuming you're using WGS84 geographic
    crs_bng = proj.Proj(init='epsg:27700')  # use a locally appropriate projected CRS
    # then cast your geographic coordinate pair to the projected system
    x, y = proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_bng, s['gps_lng'], s['gps_lat'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but I'm not sure its a good thing. I'd work in EPSG:27700 because all my other map data is most likely to have this, and if I lose the projection info for something with a custom CRS then guessing it is very very hard.

But here's how to do it:

Suppose we start at 3W, 58N. What's that in EPSG:27700?

```
>>> proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_bng, -3,58)
(340989.6785735455, 901635.9303086236)
```

The underlying description of EPSG:27700 can be looked up at SpatialReference https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/proj4/ and is:

```
>>> bng = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"
>>>
```

Note the `x_0` and `y_0` offset parameters. You need to adjust these offsets by your start coordinate so that your start coordinate projects to (0,0). I'm rounding it to integers here but for precision use the full decimal value:

```
>>> -100000-901635
-1001635
>>> 400000-340989
59011
>>>
```

Now create a projection string like EPSG:27700 but with those new offsets:

```
>>> cust = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=59011 +y_0=-1001635 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"
```

and a corresponding `pyproj` object:

```
>>> crs_cust = proj.Proj(cust)
```

If we got this right then 3W 58N should project to (0,0):

```
>>> proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_cust, -3,58)
(0.6785735454977839, 0.930308623588644)
```

which is close enough (these are in metres) and  I think the remaining fraction of a metre is due to my integer rounding. Try it with the full decimal and you should get (0,0), or very very close to it.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer. 

But now that you have shown me the projection string, is it possible to simply adapt the projection string? E.G. in you example changing

>>> cust = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=59011 +y_0=-1001635 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"

to
'''
>>> cust = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=58+lon_0=-3 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=59011 +y_0=-1001635 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: sorry for the bad editing in my comment before, it took me to long to edit it...

Comment: You are free to create any projection string you want. The one you spelled out is a transverse mercator centred on 58N 3W with that coordinate origin offset. If that translates your origin lat-long to 0,0 then go ahead. I'm not sure it will though, maybe the +x_0, y_0 need to be 0 if you set the +lat_0,+lon_0 to your point. Try it and see.

Comment: The trouble with offsetting the x0 and y0 position I see, is that it does not preserve the orientation of North & West. When the offset is large, (say 1/4 around the world, in the middle of the atlantic) the local south-north/east-west axis do not align with the true axis... Don't you think?

Comment: You can't use a transverse mercator projection outside a narrowish range of longitude. There's no projected (ie cartesian) system that works well over the whole globe because it's not flat. If you want to preserve N up you need to use a system appropriate to the longitude, which is why there are a number of "UTM" (Universal Transverse Mercator) projections recommended over a number of longitude ranges.

Comment: Hello, okay thanks for the explanation. So the real question here, how can I identify an appropriate local mercato system which is suitable for the lat/long which I want to set up my system to? How can I do that?

Comment: That's a whole new question and likely already has an answer here. You might not even want to use a Mercator system (which is a cylindrical projecton) - for a small region a local planar zenithal projection might be usable. It all depends on the details!!