# Converting point coordinate from local Cartesian to WGS 84 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, cartesian

I need to convert some cartesian (x,y) meter points coordinate from an origin to WGS 84 using QGIS 3.x API.

I have the lat and long of the origin: lat is +44.0 lon is +9.0 degrees.  I try to make a simple test in C++, if i try to convert a point which coordinates are 0,0 the result must be lat +44 and long 9 degrees.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <qgscoordinatereferencesystem.h>
#include <qgscoordinatetransformcontext.h>
#include <qgsgeometry.h>
#include <qgsgeometryengine.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    QgsApplication::initQgis();

    // Create a local Cartesian CRS with origin at lat=44, lon=9
    QString projString = "+proj=cart +lon_0=9 +lat_0=44 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem cartCRS;
    cartCRS.createFromProj(projString);

    // Create a point in the local Cartesian coordinates
    QgsPointXY point(0, 0);

    // Create a coordinate transform from the local Cartesian CRS to WGS84 CRS
    QgsCoordinateTransform coordTransform(cartCRS, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::fromEpsgId(4326));

    // Transform the point to latitude and longitude
    QgsPointXY latLon = coordTransform.transform(point);

    // Print the resulting latitude and longitude
    qDebug() << "Latitude:" << latLon.y() << ", Longitude:" << latLon.x();

    QgsApplication::exitQgis();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But I received wrong values: Latitude 9 Longitude 90. What am I doing wrong?

If you have a Python code for me is OK!

Comment: Can you check your projString as valid with QGIS?

Comment: Checking the string with qgis return true... so i think it is ok, but the conversion does not work..r

Comment: Have you tried pyproj?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330445/generating-custom-projection-in-pyproj

Comment: ..sorry buy i must use only QGis...